# Controlling Python 3.3 stdio line termination on windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.3

The following code...

```
import sys

if sys.platform == "win32":
    import os, msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)

sys.stdout.write("This is a sample line of text\n")
```

...results in the stdio output ending with `0x0d` followed by `0x0a`.  stdio is set to binary mode.  Why is the `write()` call still substituting `\r\n` for `\n`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running this under Cygwin, [`sys.platform`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.platform) will be `'cygwin'` rather than `'win32'`, but you'll still get line-ending conversion.  Are you sure the `setmode` is actually running?

Comment: Thanks, but cygwin is not being used.